# Find Missing Values in MySQL Table from another Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

**TEST**
This table contains the following fields:
ID 
theTimeStamp,
TagName

[image]
**locationNames**
This table contains two fields:
LocationName
delay
[image]

Right now I have a query that can compare the two tables, and return location names that have not been recorded in the test folder in the past x minutes (this is derived from the delay field). The values of `test.tagName` and `locationNames.locationName` are identical.

Here's what that query looks like:

```
SELECT locationName as LN 
  FROM locationNames 
 WHERE locationName NOT IN
    (SELECT tagName 
       FROM test 
      WHERE theTimeStamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL delay MINUTE) 
   AND locationType <> 'System Event'`
```

What I need to do now, is to add theTimeStamp of the last entry for a location (from the `test` table to the returned value.

Desired Output:

tagName/LocationName |  theTimeStamp(timeStamp of the last entry matching the tag/location name)

Location X           |  2018-04-13 21:08:22

Location Y           |  2018-04-13 11:00:19

How would I go about accomplishing that?

Comment: Add sample data and desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Fahad. I've added the data sample/structure and desired output

Comment: One more thing, do not put images it will hard for us to create sample output. Try adding this in you select clause. (select max(theTimeStamp) from test t1 where t1.tagName = locationNames.locationName ) as timestamp

Comment: I might be making a mistake on my end with the placement of your code. Could you please send through the full query?

Comment: SELECT locationName as LN ,(select max(theTimeStamp) from test t1 where t1.tagName = locationNames.locationName )
  FROM locationNames 
 WHERE locationName NOT IN
    (SELECT tagName 
       FROM test 
      WHERE theTimeStamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL delay MINUTE) 
   AND locationType <> 'System Event'`

Comment: Thanks Fahad. This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to only search the top 1000 records? Currently I have 50000 records in the database, and it takes a while to execute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170835/discussion-between-fahad-anjum-and-sam).